# How can I use CAS (Compare-and-swap) in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization, concurrency, processor

I've read about the possibility to use CAS instruction of the processor, using Java.

As I googled for an examples, I only found classes such as
[SimulatedCAS](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp11234/).
This class is obviously only a simulation of CAS (as its name implies...), using commmon "synchronized" on it's class methods.

So I wonder, how can one really use the CAS instruction using Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into classes like `AtomicBoolean` and `AtomicReference`. They're abstractions that do what you want, but aren't actually *on* the CPU.

One pattern I've used is for thread-safe state keeping.

```
private final AtomicBoolean isClosed = new AtomicBoolean(false);

...

public void close() {
    if (this.isClosed.compareAndSet(false, true) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Various low-level routines like `AtomicBoolean.compareAndSet` have fast paths ("intrinsics") through the JVM (at least hotspot) so they quickly boil down to hardware-specific instructions. On x86, for example, it ends up issuing one of the `cmpxchg` family of instructions.